# WELD-000143: Container lifecycle event method invoked outside of extension observer method invocation. on websphere liberty server

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I am trying to migrate an application that was running on the Websphere onto 8.5.5 server onto Websphere liberty server. After the WAR is deployed on the liberty, I am getting the following exception. The application is a REST service built on jersey and I have included the Jersey jars in the POM.

```
 000001d7 com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet

    E Exception occurred when intialization
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000143: Container lifecycle event method invoked outside of extension observer method invocation.
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerEvent.checkWithinObserverNotification(ContainerEvent.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.getAnnotatedType(AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.java:56)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.jcdi.JCDIComponentProviderFactory.init(JCDIComponentProviderFactory.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:278)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:566)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:211)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:333)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:497)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:598)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.proceed(ProbeFilter.java:329)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.proceed(ProbeFilter.java:312)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.InvocationMonitor$Action.perform(InvocationMonitor.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:338)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter.embedInfoSnippet(ProbeFilter.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1009)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:412)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:371)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:329)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[2/6/19 11:43:14:282 EST] 000001d7 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              E SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [BlueConnectRestServices] in application [EnterpriseBenefitsAndAccumsWrapperServiceV2WAR]: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000143: Container lifecycle event method invoked outside of extension observer method invocation.
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerEvent.checkWithinObserverNotification(ContainerEvent.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.getAnnotatedType(AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.java:56)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.jcdi.JCDIComponentProviderFactory.init(JCDIComponentProviderFactory.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:278)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:566)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:211)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:333)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:497)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:598)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.proceed(ProbeFilter.java:329)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.proceed(ProbeFilter.java:312)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.InvocationMonitor$Action.perform(InvocationMonitor.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:338)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter.embedInfoSnippet(ProbeFilter.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4962)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1009)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:412)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:371)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:329)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[2/6/19 11:43:14:283 EST] 000001d7 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5006)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1009)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:412)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:371)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:329)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:340)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter.embedInfoSnippet(ProbeFilter.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4962)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:366)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:598)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.proceed(ProbeFilter.java:329)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.proceed(ProbeFilter.java:312)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.InvocationMonitor$Action.perform(InvocationMonitor.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.probe.ProbeFilter$FilterAction.doFilter(ProbeFilter.java:338)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000143: Container lifecycle event method invoked outside of extension observer method invocation.
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerEvent.checkWithinObserverNotification(ContainerEvent.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.getAnnotatedType(AbstractProcessInjectionTarget.java:56)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.jcdi.JCDIComponentProviderFactory.init(JCDIComponentProviderFactory.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:278)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:566)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:211)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:333)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:497)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:297)
    ... 34 more
```

Please look into the error and advice me on how to resolve this exception. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: I can't say what the issue is without the full stack trace (check in `wlp/usr/servers/<YOUR_SERVER>/logs/messages.log`), can you update your question to include at least the full stack? Also, I suspect the issue may be related to including Jersey (and its dependencies) inside your application. Do you need Jersey specific function, or would Liberty's default JAX-RS engine (Apache CXF) be sufficient? You will likely run into less issues if you use Liberty's default JAX-RS engine instead of bringing your own.

Comment: "The root cause of this bug is definitely **pilot error**, but [read on](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2331)." ... "the only problem I had was that *the (Extension observer) method was* `static`."

Comment: @Andy Guibert - Thanks for your input. This was an existing application which was using jersey and I am planing to use the same code base on liberty too. I have updated the trace based on your comment. Please take a look into it and let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

My application uses Jersey and I was adding webprofile 7.0 as on of the features to the liberty server. Webprofile 7.0 by default enables Jaxrs feature on liberty and it was having conflicts. So, disabling the webprofile 7.0 feature did the trick for me and my application ran without any exceptions.